# Delete a row referenced by a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables, table1, table2.
 **Table2** is connected to **table1** with a foreign key. 
I want to delete a row from **table1**, without losing the data in **table2**.
 How can I solve the problem, I tried with a trigger that eliminates the primary or foreign key constraint, but an error say that the table in which I want to delete does not exists!!

Comment: See the docs here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-createtable.html . Look for FOREIGN KEY section. You are probably looking for ON DELETE SET NULL. This will leave the child row(table 2) but with the foreign key column(s) set to NULL.

Comment: I don't want to set null on the referenced table, I want the original value to remain despite I am deleting the tuple to which it is referenced

Comment: Then you can't have a FOREIGN KEY. You will need to maintain the relationship yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple ways to do this :

1 - Remove foreign key constraint (ALTER TABLE table2 DROP CONSTRAINT FK_Column)

2 - Use soft delete for table1

3 - Make table2 foreign key nullable and and use "On Delete Set Null"

Comment: Once the Fkey constraint on Table 2 has been eliminated with a trigger on Table1, do I have to add the constraint again?

Comment: I created a trigger before delete on Table1 and inserted Alter table table2 delete constraint fkey. It gives me an error saying that Table2 doesn't exist

Comment: This is not going to end well. You can't have a part time FK. You either have to deal with the rules for FK's or not use one.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have it both ways.  That is, you can't have a foreign key definition that is there where the referenced value is there.  But it doesn't complain when the referenced value is deleted.

The *purpose* of a foreign key constraint is to enforce data integrity.

One reaction is that you don't really have a foreign key constraint.  So, don't declare  it as such.  Obviously, you have a column in `table2` that is only a part-time reference to `table1.

For your particular purpose, though, I would suggest that you consider a soft-delete.  That is, have a flag is `table1` for `isDeleted` or better yet, `deletionDatetime`.  Then you can keep the row in `table1`, have a full-time foreign key reference, and not have to worry about relational integrity.